# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php4496.tmp' to 'public/upload/member_new\BOm3f0T1kL.png' in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I've tried like this.

```html
if ($imageimage) {
    if ($member->image != null) {
        @unlink($member->image);
    }
    $image_name = Str::random(10);
    $ext = strtolower($imageimage->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $image_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
    $upload_path = 'public/upload/member_new/';

    $image_description = $upload_path . $image_name;
    $imageimage->move($upload_path, $image_name);
    if ($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='png'|| $ext=='jpeg'){
        $member->image = $image_description;
        dd('success');
    }else{
        Toastr::error('message', 'Image is not valid!!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Could not move the file "C:\xampp\tmp\php4496.tmp" to "public/upload/member_new\BOm3f0T1kL.png" (move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php4496.tmp' to 'public/upload/member_new\BOm3f0T1kL.png').

Comment: try with `$upload_path = public_path('upload/member_new'));` and make sure u have directory in the public folder

Comment: Thanks but not working. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use storage laravel.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name

```
$request->file->storeAs($path, $file_name, $disk);
```